# Что означает message.from_user (в данном примере идентифицируется бот или юзер бота)? Для чего нужен message.from_user и bot.get_me()?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я только знакомлюсь с ботами и учиться питону! Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означает message.from_user (в данном примере идентифицируется бот или юзер бота)? Для чего нужен конкретно в этом примере message.from_user и bot.get_me()? Почему без их указания не обойтись?

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!"
                     "Я - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот".format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
                     parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего - переменная `from_user` содержит данные о пользователе, который отправил сообщение `message`, а метод `get_me` возвращает данные о самом боте. На ваш вопрос, "почему нельзя обойтись без них", могу посоветовать сначала пройти основы работы на Python (а в данном случае форматирование текста) и после уже приступать к программированию более сложных вещей.

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте полную версию кода, чтобы можно было понять, что и откуда берется.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял что часть кода: "Сообщение".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()).
Означает что данное сообщение форматируется и отправляется именно как это указанно в ответ на сообщение пользователя, для такой строгости как раз таки и нужны методы message.from_user и bot.get_me(), так же более подробно вы можете ознакомится с этими методами вот здесь https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user